# Copy one cell from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having difficulty creating a SQL statement. There is a password in a test database that I have forgotten, and I need to replace it with a known password from a different test database. The password is stored as binary, so I can't seem to right click on it to copy and paste, so I am trying to write a SQL statement. Unfortunately, although I can figure out how to insert a row from one database to another, and copy a cell from one table to another, I can't seem to get the cell from one database to another.

Thus, what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
use TestDb1
GO

UPDATE TestDb1.[Staff].[User] (Password)
{
    SELECT TestDb2.[Staff].[User].Password
    FROM TestDb2.[Staff].[User]
    WHERE UserName = 'admin'
} 
WHERE UserName = 'admin'
```

I know, this isn't even close to being correct, but I suppose if I was close I wouldn't really need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI TSQL syntax for UPDATES with joins can be confusing (so confusing that I made an error the first time around :) ):

```
UPDATE u1 
Set u1.Password = u2.Password 
from TestDb1.[Staff].[User] u1
join TestDb2.[Staff].[User] u2 on u2.UserName = u1.UserName 
WHERE u2.UserName = 'admin'
```

[[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5b53/9) that shows the syntax against the same table.]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm pretty new to SQL, and so am not sure what the u2 represents. I get a u2.Password could not be bound error.

Comment: `u2` is an alias for `TestDb2.[Staff]`.  In the example, you have two tables with the same name, but from different DB's.  Does the User table have a Password column?

Comment: I remember aliases now, but still seem to be getting a Password could not be bound error on u2.Password in line 2, and an incorrect syntax near join error. Any ideas?